# How to make a field extension chain

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I'm looking for $\alpha$  such that $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{17})\subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{17}+\zeta_{17}^{-1})\subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{17})$ will be a chain of extensions with extension degree of 2 for every extension, when $\zeta_{17}=e^{2\pi i/17}$. 
How do I approach that? (need a direction, not solution. thanks)

Comment: Do you know how to construct the minimum polynomials of $\sqrt{17}$ and $\zeta_{17}+\zeta_{17}^{-1}$?

Comment: You can approach this step by step. The last extension has degree $2$ for an easy reason, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887960/degree-of-mathbbq-zeta-n-over-mathbbq-zeta-n-zeta-n-1). The first one, too, because $x^2-17$ is irreducible. So there is not too much left.

Comment: Gaussian periods?

Comment: yes, I just built the polynoms. seems to work.
and I looked for Gaussian periods in Wikipedia. Looks very similar to my problem, but I'm not sure what did you want to say about them. 
@LordSharktheUnknown can you clarify? thanks